# Background SVG scaling issue in Edge, Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, microsoft-edge, antialiasing

I have a div with an SVG background. It renders smoothly on Chrome but jagged on IE and Firefox.

The css code:

```
.blog-menu-logo {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 29px;
   width: 166px;
   margin: 18px 20px 18px 5px;
   background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/hemingway-child/svgs/logo-small.svg);
   background-size: cover;
   image-rendering: auto;
```

}

And the SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1_xA0_Image_1_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 x="0px" y="0px" width="415px" height="72.5px" viewBox="283 49.25 415 72.5" enable-background="new 283 49.25 415 72.5"
 xml:space="preserve">
<image overflow="visible" enable-background="new" width="982" height="172" id="Layer_1_xA0_Image" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...
```

Which results in:

Chrome
[image]

Firefox
[image]

Edge
[image]

Note that FF and Edge look even more jagged on my browser. The screen snipping tools anti-aliased them slightly.

Comment: can you make a fiddle with the svg.

Comment: Thats not an SVG, it is a PNG image with a SVG wrapper around it. You would get the same result if you  opend the data url inside the SVG in a new browser window, saved it to a .png file and set that (or the data url) as the background image in your CSS.

Comment: Really? I didn't realise that. I'll have to search for the correct settings in Illustrator when I save as SVG. Thank you!